# Setting a HTML Date element's value with a PHP variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

so I currently have 6 HTML date elements on my page I'm trying to make them save what was entered so that when the page is reloaded they still have the data entered saved. So I have my PHP set up to when the form is posted the data is saved to a text document on the site directory. Which works perfectly, now I've also created PHP variables to get the document information that was saved which again works. Now when I run my Javascript I find that the PHP variables have gone across and are outputting the correct information. However, the date elements stay empty. Anyone know why this might be?

**Element Example Output**

```
window.onload = function (){
    var date1Value = 2016-10-01;
    var date2Value = 2016-10-02;
    var date3Value = 2016-10-03;
    var date4Value = 2016-10-04;
    var date5Value = 2016-10-05;
    var date6Value = 2016-10-06;

    document.getElementById("date1").value = date1Value;
    document.getElementById("date2").value = date2Value;
    document.getElementById("date3").value = date3Value;
    document.getElementById("date4").value = date4Value;
    document.getElementById("date5").value = date5Value;
    document.getElementById("date6").value = date6Value;
}
```

**PHP Snippet**

```
<?php
$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date1.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$setA5 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);
$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date2.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$setA6 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date3.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$setA11 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);
$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date4.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$setA12 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date5.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$setA17 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);
$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date6.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$setA18 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $date1 = $_POST['date_1A5'];
    $date2 = $_POST['date_1A6'];
    $date3 = $_POST['date_2A5'];
    $date4 = $_POST['date_2A6'];
    $date5 = $_POST['date_3A5'];
    $date6 = $_POST['date_3A6'];

    $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date1.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $date1);
    fclose($myFile);
    $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date2.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $date2);
    fclose($myFile);
    $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date3.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $date3);
    fclose($myFile);
    $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date4.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $date4);
    fclose($myFile);
    $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date5.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $date5);
    fclose($myFile);
    $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment"."/Date6.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
    fwrite($myFile, $date6);
    fclose($myFile);
}
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function (){
        var date1Value = <?php echo $setA5;?>;
        var date2Value = <?php echo $setA6;?>;
        var date3Value = <?php echo $setA11;?>;
        var date4Value = <?php echo $setA12;?>;
        var date5Value = <?php echo $setA17;?>;
        var date6Value = <?php echo $setA18;?>;

        document.getElementById("date1").value = date1Value;
        document.getElementById("date2").value = date2Value;
        document.getElementById("date3").value = date3Value;
        document.getElementById("date4").value = date4Value;
        document.getElementById("date5").value = date5Value;
        document.getElementById("date6").value = date6Value;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action=thisPage.php>
            <input type="date" name="date_1A5" id="date1">
            <input type="date" name="date_1A6" id="date2">
            <input type="date" name="date_2A5" id="date3">
            <input type="date" name="date_2A6" id="date4">
            <input type="date" name="date_3A5" id="date5">
            <input type="date" name="date_3A6" id="date6">
        </form>
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the example output, as it shows exactly what's wrong. :)

First though, I'd just like to point out that there is no jQuery in this code. What you have is plain JavaScript.

Then, the problem is that you're missing quotes around the dates in the JavaScript portion. Add those around the PHP code that prints the dates, and it should work.

PS: You really should look into using databases, or at least a single file, to contain these dates. Multiple files like these is not only inefficient, but is also quite messy.
A quick example for how you can use a single file:

```
// The file() function automatically creates an array on newlines.
$dates = file ("dates.txt");

if (!$dates) {
    // Show an error message on missing dates.
}

?>
<script>

// $dates[0] contains the first date, increase index by 1 to get the next date.
document.getElementById ('date_1').value = '<?php echo $dates[0]; ?>'
```

PPS: You also should look into input validation, to ensure that the data you get back from the user is indeed a valid date. The easiest way to do this, is by trying to parse it with the `DateTime` class.

```
// If the user has submitted data...
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    $dates = array ();

    // Ensure we get a valid date.
    $date[0] = DateTime::createFromFormat ('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_1']);
    if (!$dates[0]) {
        // Invalid date, handle it.
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, just wanted to add thanks for clearing this up and going the extra for helping me here. I will definitely start trying to incorporate these methods.

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad I could help. :) Rember that I've barely scratched the surface here when it comes to securing your scripts, and there is a LOT more to learn on this subject. I strongly recommend reading more up on this before putting anything available on the internet.

Comment: Thanks again I will definitely have a further look into this.

Answer (score -1):

When you output the date in javascript, concatenate quotes around it like this:

```
var date1Value = " + <?php echo $setA5;?> + ";
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. You seem to be confused by the switching of modes, and mixing of languages. Remember that the PHP-code in the middle is parsed, and replaced, before the JS ever comes into play. ;)